# Deploying Rails war to Tomcat6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, tomcat6, warbler

I'm deploying a rails application to a tomcat6 server.

Everything seems to be working fine, but I get a 500 error when I try to access any page on the site.  The error isn't very informative (from the tomcat log file):

```
Dec 16, 2012 11:37:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: INFO: failed to capture exception message
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (ArgumentError) wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
    at RUBY.capture(file:/usr/local/tomcat6/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib/gems-gems-jruby-rack-1.1.12-lib-jruby-rack-1.1.12.jar!/jruby/rack/capture.rb:48)
    at RUBY.capture(file:/usr/local/tomcat6/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib/gems-gems-jruby-rack-1.1.12-lib-jruby-rack-1.1.12.jar!/jruby/rack/capture.rb:59)
    at RUBY.capture(file:/usr/local/tomcat6/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib/gems-gems-jruby-rack-1.1.12-lib-jruby-rack-1.1.12.jar!/jruby/rack/capture.rb:69)
    at RUBY.capture(file:/usr/local/tomcat6/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib/gems-gems-jruby-rack-1.1.12-lib-jruby-rack-1.1.12.jar!/jruby/rack/capture.rb:82)
    at RUBY.capture(file:/usr/local/tomcat6/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib/gems-gems-jruby-rack-1.1.12-lib-jruby-rack-1.1.12.jar!/jruby/rack/capture.rb:116)
Dec 16, 2012 11:37:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: DEBUG: resetting rack response due exception
```

Relevant lines from my `Gemfile.lock`:

```
warbler (1.3.6)
  jruby-jars (>= 1.4.0)
  jruby-rack (>= 1.0.0)
  rake (>= 0.8.7)
  rubyzip (>= 0.9.4)
jruby-jars (1.7.1)
jruby-rack (1.1.12)
rake (10.0.3)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
```

I'm running `$ rake war` with the option `config.features = %w(compiled)` in `config/warble.rb`.  I've also tried it with the `gemjar` option, and with both on, but I still get the same error message.

How can I track down this problem?

Comment: @bdares did you manage to get past it ? stuck with same problem